# How to pass a context to another widget?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm using notifications for my app with [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_local_notifications). My app consists of two widgets. The FirstPage and the SecondPage widget/class. The purpose of my FirstPage widget is to display a list of alarms/notifications that will happen in the future. While the purpose of the SecondPage widget is to create the notification.

Basically, when I open my app, it will display the FirstPage and then I can navigate to my SecondPage with the use of Navigation pushNamed.

Ideally, when I tap a notification, it will display a dialog on the FirstPage.

The problem is that, when I tap a notification, nothing appears on the FirstPage but when I navigate to my SecondPage, the dialog appears there.

I tried to pass the context of my FirstPage using a global variable to the dialog on the SecondPage:

```
BuildContext _contextOfFirst; // The global variable I used to store the context of FirstPage

...

class FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

    ...

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        _contextOfFirst = context; // FirstPage's context was stored on my global variable
    }

}

...

class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

    ...

    Future onselectNotification(String payload) async{

        print(_contextOfFirst); // Just for checking 

        showCupertinoDialog(
            context: _contextOfFirst, // I placed it here. Hoping that it will be displayed on the FirstPage
            builder: (_) => new CupertinoAlertDialog(
                title: new Text("Some Title"),
                content: new Text("$payload")
           )
        );
    }
...
}
```

Even after I passed the context of FirstPage to the dialog, still the dialog won't show on the FirstPage and when I navigate to the SecondPage, it appears in there.

I thought that by supplying the context from FirstPage to the dialog, it will make the dialog appear on the FirstPage. But I was wrong.

I would love to know where did I go wrong.

I would appreciate any enlightment from you guys.

Comment: I think we should keep the first page as the controller of the notifications and the second page as an helper only isn't we?

Comment: @Hovanes Mosoyan, thanks for the idea. I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are displaying notifications in the **First activity** and calling the `onselectNotification` where you are displaying the Dialog in the **Second activity**! which does not make sense.

So i would suggest that you place the `onselectNotification` in the **First class** and as a **Callback** call your Dialog to show up and either you set a timer or on button click you display the **Second activity** (If you shared the code of the `showCupertinoDialog` i can know what kind of scenario you are trying to achieve).

So your problem is not a context problem it is just a wrong order of calling instructions.